# Scipy.sparse multiplication error

Tags: python, scipy

I am attempting to multiply two relatively large scipy.sparse matrices. One is 100000 x 20000 and the other is 20000 x 100000. My machine has sufficient memory to handle the operation but it is by no means fast. I have tried it multiple times now and I get the same error (source code found [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/compressed.py)):

ValueError: Last value of index pointer should be less than the size of index and data arrays

I for the life of me cannot figure out what is causing the error. It seems that the index pointer is not getting scaled to the correct size when multiplied but I cannot find where the error is originating from. Any help on how to solve the error, or of any other packages that can handle the operation?

Comment: What version of scipy are you using? Would the number of non-zero entries in your resulting matrix multiplication be more than `2^31`? There was an issue with the indexing arrays being `int32`, and thus overflowing for very big arrays. Can you test with the current development version?

Comment: I upgraded to the development version and that solved the problem thank you Jaime.

Comment: Glad that helped. You may want to answer your own question, including the failing and working version numbers, for the generations to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using scipy version 0.13.0. Upgraded to current development version (0.15.0dev) and the issue appears to have been fixed.